# Make a certain key combination lead to certain page (HTML)

Tags: javascript, html

I have a website and I need the key combination `Ctrl+Alt+D` lead to a certain page on my online game. 
I believe this has something to do with Access Keys, but i'm new to coding.

An HTML or JS code solution is preferable.

Comment: Please elaborate your question and also tag your question so that people can find it appropriately

Answer (score -2):

```
function handleKeyDown(e) {
 var ctrlPressed=0;
 var altPressed=0;
 var dPressed=0;

 var evt = (e==null ? event:e);

 dPressed = evt.keyCode == 68;
 altPressed = evt.altKey;
 ctrlPressed = evt.ctrlKey;


 if (dPressed && altPressed && ctrlPressed) {
   return true;
 }else{
   return false;
 }

}

document.onkeydown = handleKeyDown;
```

Source: http://www.javascripter.net/faq/keyboard_ctrl_alt_shift.htm